# Mapping with dictionary for passing to django orm filter

Tags: python, django

I have a string which comes from UI cookie:

```
string="check_in=12-12-2022,notify=fail"
```

Here converting to dictionary as to maping with column fields with database

Converting to dictionary & mapping:

```
 dictValue=dict(item.split("=") for item in string.split(","))
```

Mapping:

```
query_to_field_mapping = {
                "Date": "checkIn__contains",
                "Status": "result"}
    query = {
                query_to_field_mapping[key]: value for key,
                value in dictValue.items()}
```

This is working Fine for passing the dictionary to django orm to filter
Like:`member.objects.filter(**query)`
But problem starts when I add more value to notify  like:

```
string="check_in=12-12-2022,notify=fail,pass,unknown"
```

Getting an error like:   **dictionary update sequence element #1 has length 1; 2 is required**

I want a dictionary in the form like:

```
query ={'checkIn__contains':12-12-2022,'result':[fail,pass,unknown]}
```

I don't want to hard code a dictionary & insert those required values.
Because some times I may not get any of the value like:
Sometime like:   `string="notify=fail,pass,unknown"`
Sometime like:   `string= "date=12-12-2022"`
Sometimes like:  `string= "date=12-12-2022,notify=fail,pass,unknown"`

Here passing query as **query to django orm to filter.
  Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can someone see the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this, with regular expressions:

```
import re

r1 = re.compile('([a-zA-Z_]+)=([^,]+)(,(.*)|$)')
r2 = re.compile('([^=,]+)(,(.*)|$)')

string = "check_in=12-12-2022,notify=fail,pass,unknown"
s = string
dct = []
while s:
    # print(s)    # uncomment these lines to
    # print(dct)  # see what each step does.
    m = r2.match(s)
    if m:
        key, val = dct[-1]
        if type(val) != list:
            val = [val]
        val.append(m.group(1))
        dct[-1] = key, val
        s = m.group(3)
    else:
        m = r1.match(s)
        if not m:
            raise ValueError("string format is wrong")
        dct.append((m.group(1), m.group(2)))
        s = m.group(4)

dct = dict(dct)
```

This is however quite a bad way to store and parse data. Why don't you use a standard format such as JSON?

Also note that using this method, `notify=fail` will result in `{'notify': 'fail'}` not `{'notify': ['fail']}`, as there is no way to know if you expect a list rather string when there is no comma in the value. So, you will have to do extra work, according to what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanx Antoine a lotttttttttttt. You saved my time. Realy helpful.

Comment: Could you please tell me on which context you are saying to use standard format as JSON?Interested to learn those also

Comment: If your data was stored as `'{"check_in": "12-12-2022", "notify": ["fail", "pass", "unknown"]}'` you would yust have to call `import json; dct = json.loads(string)`. See http://www.w3schools.com/json/ for instance.

Comment: No actually I am reading cookie apply filter on my DB.So reading from cookie as comma separated & then converting to dict then start applying to Django orm

Comment: If you have control over this cookie, what prevents you from storing the data as JSON rather than custom format?

Comment: Sorry Mistake.No issues.But how can i set as list as mentioned {'notify': ['fail']}.How to set a check ???

Comment: `if type(x) != list: x = [x]` for instance.

Comment: Thanks Bosss.Helped through out

Comment: @Antoine-Boss can You please see the Question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38116381/djangoqueryset-filter-aliasable-when-passing-dictionary-to-filter) as it is little bit related to this Question